# Nix "is site X down/working/slow" messages

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7132/is-buxfer-dead) is a perfect example of the kind of question we **don't** want on WebApps. Can you imagine how many of these we're going to get every time the intertubes have a hiccup?

Nothing against the asker, of course. He's legitimately wondering if the site is going/gone away. But it's still not the kind of question I think we want to see here.

Comment: Good thing there's a *too localized* close option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a CW question along with an answer - [How do I diagnose when and why a website is down?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/how-do-i-diagnose-when-and-why-a-website-is-down)

Feel free to make the question better and add your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we probably want a single "how do I diagnose when and why a website is down?" question.

That'd be a *great* resource, then close them all as dupes of that question.

(this sort of linking also ambiently bumps a question in the tag /faq pages)